# Bash arguments parse logic runs into infinite loop

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a loop to parse command line arguments. Everything works fine if -d or -b argument has a parameter. But when I pass -d or -b without a parameter, the script gets into infinite loop.

```
# Parse command line input
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -d) DOMAIN="$2"; shift 2;;
    -b) BITS="$2"; shift 2;;
     *) die "unrecognized argument: $1"
  esac
done
```

How to throw error on empty parameter?

Comment: If your arguments are just single-letter, you can use [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-getopts) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: One trick that would work, especially if you had some flag options (that don't take arguments) is `shift` instead of `shift 2` inside the `case`, and another `shift` after `esac` and before `done`.  The flag options wouldn't need a shift at all.  Because it would shift one argument at a time, it would get rid a stray `-b` with no argument, so the loop would terminate.  That said, the `getopts` answer is the better long-term choice.  Ad hoc solutions acquire ad hoc bugs — witness your infinite loop problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `shift n` command doesn't do anything if you try to shift more than the number of values present in the list.  That's the reason for the infinite loop in your code.

Using `getopts` is the right thing to do as it gives you a lot of flexibility.  Otherwise, you could rewrite your loop this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Parse command line input
d_flag=0
b_flag=0
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -d) 
        d_flag=1
        shift
        [[ $1 == -* ]] && continue # argument to -d not given
        DOMAIN=$1
        shift
        ;; 
    -b) 
        b_flag=1
        shift
        [[ $1 == -* ]] && continue # argument to -b not given
        BITS=$1
        shift
        ;;
     *) echo "unrecognized argument: $1"; exit 2;;
  esac
done

if [[ $d_flag = 1 && -z $DOMAIN ]]; then
    # handle error - option requires an argument
fi

if [[ $b_flag = 1 && -z $BITS ]]; then
    # handle error - option requires an argument
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Shift fails due to not enough arguments.

This problem would, however, be immediately obvious is you set your shell to fail on all errors (with `set -e`).  It makes debugging much easier in many cases by avoiding silent failures, and enforces discipline and error checking.  `set -u` causes errors on failed variable expansions, also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you always need two parameters you could change first line to:

```
while [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; do
```

Otherwise you can check the value of $2 before to enter the loop like this:

```
if [[ -z $2 ]]; then 
echo "missing second parameter"
else
#do the while loop
fi
```

Comment: This would work only when we have all options taking an argument and hence we could treat them as pairs.